# Integer solution for $Rx^2+Sy^2=1$ .

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there any integer solution in-terms of $R,S$ for the equation $Rx^2+Sy^2=1$ , .

For example $(\frac{1}{\sqrt {2R}},\frac{1}{\sqrt {2S}})$ is a solution but not integer solution .

Is there any integer solution tuple for the equation in terms of R and S?

If not , is there any simple efficient algorithm to get integer solution ?

Comment: If $R,S > 0$ then there are at most finitely many solutions, and you can try them all.  What should we assume about $R,S$?  For example, some positive real values of $R,S$ will make the solution you gave an *integer* solution.

Comment: If $R$ and $S$ are both greater than 1, can this even have an integer solution?

Comment: If you want $R,S$ to be positive integers, it would be more interesting to ask for *rational* solutions $x,y$.

Comment: [This is pretty much what we know about quadratic diophantines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html)

Answer (score 1):

If $R=1$ and $S$ is a negative integer, this is Pell's equation.  Algorithms exist to find solutions.  I don't know how simple or efficient these algorithms are, though.

If you explore that route, you might find some information on the more general case where $R$ is a positive integer and $S$ is a negative integer.

Comment: The classical [Archimedes' Cattle of the Sun Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_cattle_problem) is a good illustration of how fairly modest Pell equations can have unpredictably large fundamental solutions.